# Man in the middle attack in LAN

Tags: security, diffie-hellman, man-in-the-middle

I am pretty new in this kind of things.

I have a local area network, accessed by some users via cable some and via wifi others.
I have developed a local application in php which receives only some of the LAN clients as authentic users; they can be identified by the system with an algorithm of key exchange similar to Diffie–Hellman's, to estabilish a secret key. The client then asks to be identified throug such a channel.

The problem is, MITM attack is possible in this kind of situation. I read wikipedia about how such an attack is executed: somebody listens the messages of the two, and puts himself between them creating two different secret keys for the client and server.

This attack is reality, so it must be possible; but I do not understand how it happens in a LAN: 
the attacker can listen to the messages, and inject message of his own, impersoning the two subjects of the communications by forging https' IP fields if necessary... 
But he can't prevent the original unforged message to reach, concurrently (but also later, because of forging process taking the attacker computer some time) with his malevolent forged one, the recipient! Especially in a wifi connection, which cannot be cut off for a single user, for example cutting his cable.
So, client and server receive two different http requests from each other, a true and a forged one; isn't this a way for them to recognize that such an attack is in progress?

Maybe this question is newby-ous; as I said, I am pretty new at this.

Comment: this should be migrated to security_stackexchange_com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is a scenario where you would use a digital signature (which also uses the idea that asymmetric encryption/Diffie-Hellman uses, that is "public and private key") to sign your messages.

The MITM attacker can not forge a message with a bad "from" and then sign it with the private signature of the original sender. The recipient uses the public part of the signature/certificate to validate the message. So that way he will not only know he is being attacked but also which message is genuine.